# How do the choices affect the story?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one

I've just started playing The Walking Dead on Xbox 360. The game offers you multiple choices in conversations mostly to be answered in a limited time. How do these choices affect the course of the game? Do they affect the difficulty level? Can they change the direction of the story dramatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. They'll change how characters think of you, dialogue, and who dies first, but it all has one ending, one script, and one plot. If you die, you'll just have a "you died" screen and a retry button.

Answer (score 1):

Yes some choices you make will dramatically affect the storyline.

> For example when Larry was arguing with Kenny I told him to knock his butt out.  I ended up losing his daughters trust and in episode 2 she wouldn't speak to me except when she had to. But I think that's because I called her a b***h.

I Think all your choices will end up changing the end result in episode 5. Those little notes at the top of the screen hint at that.

Comment: That's not that dramatic a change.